# Getting VS-code on Windows-10 to use WSL's Python environment

Tags: visual-studio-code

Motivation: If possible, I'm eventually hoping to get VS-code (under Windows-10) to use WSL(2)'s Python3.9 because 'pip install rebound' only completes successfully under WSL. If there are things I can do to make that work, I'd love to hear them.

Journey: Started here: https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/09/24/wsl-setup-vs-code-for-python-development/ Visual Studio Code and WSL(2) were already installed; so trying to get Windows Terminal to satisfy the 'prerequisites'. Followed https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=us&rtc=1 to get Windows Terminal, but Windows Store hangs when I try to get Windows Terminal, so... https://4sysops.com/archives/install-windows-terminal-without-the-store-on-windows-server/ claims it's possible to get Windows Terminal without the Store. Inconveniently, 'PowerShell$ Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx' takes infinite time to install, stuck in "Hang on while we get your app's information..."

Summary: Windows Terminal sounds nice to have, but the 'real' objective is still that stated in Motivation above.

Notes: FYI, Apps & Features does not have a Windows Store to manage.